# Can anyone tell me how can I store an array of custom objects in Firebase Firestore (Android)

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, development-environment

Can anyone tell me how can I store an array of custom objects in Firebase Firestore (Android) from one app and then retrieve the objects back to another app (**Both the apps are connected to the same Firebase project**).
I tried using Maps and I was able to store the list of orders but I cannot retrieve the ArrayList back.
Here is how I did it:

```
Map<String, ArrayList<OrderItemModel>> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(currentOrderNumber, orderList);
firebaseFirestore.collection("orders").document(college).set(map, SetOptions.merge())
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Order placed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Couldn't place order. Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
});
```

When I tried to retrieve it using documentSnapshot.getData() it returns Map<String, Object>. I tried to cast the Object to ArrayList and use it in a RecyclerView adapter but it shows error.
Here is my OrderItemModel class:

```
public class OrderItemModel {

    private String itemName;
    private String itemPrice;
    private String itemCount;

    public OrderItemModel() {
    }

    public OrderItemModel(String itemName, String itemPrice, String itemCount) {
        this.itemName = itemName;
        this.itemPrice = itemPrice;
        this.itemCount = itemCount;
    }

    public String getItemName() {
        return itemName;
    }

    public void setItemName(String itemName) {
        this.itemName = itemName;
    }

    public String getItemPrice() {
        return itemPrice;
    }

    public void setItemPrice(String itemPrice) {
        this.itemPrice = itemPrice;
    }

    public String getItemCount() {
        return itemCount;
    }

    public void setItemCount(String itemCount) {
        this.itemCount = itemCount;
    }
}
```

My Firebase Firestore:
[image]

I have been trying to figure this out for a week and still haven't gotten anywhere. I've tried a lot of things but still coudn't find the solution. If anything is not clear please ask. Plsease help.
Thank you.

**Edit:**

I am retrieving the data in the following manner:

```
firebaseFirestore.collection("orders").document(college).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = task.getResult();
            assert documentSnapshot != null;
            if (documentSnapshot.exists()) {
                Map<String, Object> listMap = documentSnapshot.getData();
                for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : listMap.entrySet()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: Key: " + entry.getKey() + ", Value: " + entry.getValue().toString());
                    if (entry.getKey().equals(currentOrderNumber)) {
                        orderList.addAll((Collection<? extends OrderItemModel>) entry.getValue());
                    }
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: ArrayList: " + orderList.get(0).getItemName());         // This line shows error.
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(ShowOrder.this, "Order document not found!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(ShowOrder.this, "An error occurred while fetching the data.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});
```

As I understand I successfully retrieve the data in the form of Map<String, Object> but cannot extract the ArrayList from it.

```
Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: ArrayList: " + orderList.get(0).getItemName());
```

The above line shows the following error:

```
2021-01-10 23:48:40.192 8747-8747/com.campuscanteen.main E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.campuscanteen.main, PID: 8747
    java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to com.campuscanteen.main.Models.OrderItemModel
        at com.campuscanteen.main.ShowOrder$2.onComplete(ShowOrder.java:89)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzj.run(Unknown Source:4)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:230)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7815)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:526)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1034)
```

**Edit 2:**

I made a class as you suggested:

```
public class OrderList {
    public List<OrderItemModel> modelList;

    public OrderList() {
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "OrderList{" +
                "modelList=" + modelList +
                '}';
    }
}
```

And tried these lines to retrieved the data:

```
List<OrderItemModel> myLists = documentSnapshot.toObject(OrderList.class).modelList;
                        Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: ArrayList: " + myLists.toString());  // myLists here has null value.
```

This way the list has null value. Pardon my lack of knowledge and please help.

Comment: Can you provide your code when you are trying to retrieve data? What error does it show? - also provide an exception

Comment: Like the exception says, you are trying to cast HashMap into OrderItemModel. So I guess entry.getValue() returns type HashMap and you want to cast it to OrderItemModel in code line 89.

Comment: @SlothCoding Yes. I also tried documentSnapshot.getData().get(currentOrderNumber) and the result is same. I don't know what to do. Can you tell me a way to get the arrayList back. I want to use the arrayList for a recyclerView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the following error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to com.campuscanteen.main.Models.OrderItemModel

Because you are trying to cast an object of type HashMap to an object of type OrderItemModel, which is actually not possible in Java.

Seeing your screenshot, your document holds a property of type array called "201". This array contains in terms "OrderItemModel" objects. I'm not sure why would you call this array like this, as "orderItems" might be more meaningful. However, to map that array to a `List<OrderItemModel>`, you should simply create a class with a single property:

```
class OrdersDocument {
    public List<OrderItemModel> orderItems;
}
```

Now, you can create a reference to the document, attach a listener and convert the array to a list of custom objects:

```
List<OrderItemModel> orderItems = document.toObject(OrdersDocument.class).orderItems;
```

As explained in my article from the following link:

> [How to map an array of objects from Cloud Firestore to a List of objects?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-map-an-array-of-objects-from-cloud-firestore-to-a-list-of-objects-122e579eae10)

Comment: I'm storing the orders placed by a customer. '201' is the order number and the array is the items in that order. I tried as you said, but the arraylist I get has null value. I don't understand how's that gonna work (sorry, I'm new to Android Development). My question is - since we have stored a map<String, Arraylist<OrderItemModel>> in Firestore, then how can we retrieve it with a class which has an arraylist as its member (shoudn't it be a map too). And I had already looked into your article before asking the question here, but it didn't help. I'll add the code under 'Edit 2:'. Please help.

Comment: Please edit your question with the code (not my answer). If you get a null value, it means that most likely you didn't change the document ID from "201" to "orderItems". No, it shouldn't be a Map. You can get the entire document as a Map, but the array should be mapped to a List. Try it again and tell me if it works.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this time I'm getting error saying -            
 "java.lang.RuntimeException: No properties to serialize found on class com.campuscanteen.main.OrderList"

Comment: You are getting that error because the array property in the document it's still named "201", which is **not** correct. The property should be named "orderItems". Remove that data and add it again. If you need an ID of the order, you can add it as a property of the class, right?

Comment: I'd already changed the document name, but I found out that I was getting that error because I had a private member in OrderList class and there were no getters. Just adding a getter method solved the problem. And thanks a lot man. You were great help. And I would like to contact you again for in the future for help. Thanks again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227179/discussion-between-sam-and-alex-mamo).